# Azure table storage - pattern for parent-child (self referencing schema)

Tags: azure, data-modeling, azure-table-storage

Using `Windows Azure Table Storage` (WATS) and trying to update the app to use Azure. I've read many articles, and am not sure on the best approach for this, that is parent to child in a self referencing model.

ie a single parent message could have many child sub-messages. In a DB model, it would be a self referencing table.

How would I best structure this for `WATS` so that when I make a query "Give me 10 parent records", it will also return all the child-messages belonging to the parent...

The entity of the message / submessage as below. I've tried to define the PK and RK as below:

```
public class TextCacheEntity : AzureTableEntity // custom table inherits AzureTableEntity
{
    public override void GenerateKeys()
    {
        PartitionKey = string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}", MessageType, AccountId.PadThis(), ParentMessageId );
        RowKey = string.Format("{0}_{1}", DateOfMessage.Ticks.ReverseTicks(), MessageId);
    }
    public string MessageType { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfMessage { get; set; }
    public string MessageId { get; set; }
    public string ParentMessageId { get; set; }
    // other properties...
}
```

I thought of an implementation so the child messages store the parentMessagesId, and the parent parentMessageId would be empty.

The pattern would then be

1. Get the parent messages

   ```
   .Where(o => o.ParititionKey == "Parent_000000000000001_").Take(10)
   ```
2. Get the child messages. Iterate through all the parent messages and using a parallel for loop

   ```
   .Where(o => o.ParititionKey == "Child_000000000000001_" + parentMessageId)
   ```

But the problem is that this will result in 11 queries !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example by Scott Densmore:

http://scottdensmore.typepad.com/blog/2011/04/multi-entity-schema-tables-in-windows-azure.html

Comment: That is very good - downloaded the sample sln and looking at the article by Jeffrey Richter at http://www.wintellect.com/Articles/Working%20with%20Azure%20Tables%20with%20Multiple%20Entity%20Schemas%20by%20Jeffrey%20Richter.pdf

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for !! Accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the same PK for both.  There are a couple reasons to do this, but one good one is that you can then also issue batch commands for parent and children at once and achieve a type of consistent transaction.  Also, when they share the same PK within the same table, it means they are going to be colocated together and served from the same partition.  You are less likely to continuation tokens (but you should still expect them).  To differentiate between parent and children you can either add an attribute or use the RowKey perhaps.

The only trick to this (and the model you already ahve), is that if the parent and children are not the same CLR type, you will have issues with serialization in WCF DataServices.  You can fix this of course by creating an uber-CLR type that has both child and parent properties or you can override serialization with the ReadingEntity event and handle it yourself.

Anyhow, use the same PK for both children and parent.  Then when you search PK ranges you will always get parents and children returned at once (you can discriminate with a Where clause predicate if you wish).

Comment: Thanks, the idea was there, but it would be alot of reinventing the wheel. Euginio's answer has concrete code into implementing the solution !

Comment: Everything I just wrote is exactly what Eugenio pointed you to.  I guess you don't care about how things are done, but just want to cut and paste.  Also, I wonder who helped write that particular bit of work?  Check the contributors.

Comment: Definitely care how its done and seeing actual code, rather trying to reinvent it myself saves alot of hassle, and just use the bits that I need. Isn't that the purpose of software development... Couldn't find the contributors, but if you did, could have just posted the link

Comment: There is no reinventing the wheel here.  I answered you with the most correct answer with clear explanation of why as well.  You chose to accept an answer that did not explain why, but only showed how.  The irony is that I was the SME for the other answer too.  Most folks would have bumped mine at least and accepted the other.

Next time I see Eugenio... I am taking him down. ;)

Comment: I stand corrected, your method is correct, basically an overview of what the documentation says, and did give me some ideas, albeit, still requiring a lot of research to actually implement it.